# Unity Program crashes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here my unity program crashes everytime i start it :

```
Mono path[0] = 'D:/Unity Pixel Jump/export/Save the Ghost_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = 'D:/Unity Pixel Jump/export/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Initialize engine version: 2019.4.17f1 (667c8606c536)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path D:/Unity Pixel Jump/export/Save the Ghost_Data/UnitySubsystems
Forcing GfxDevice: Null
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0
NullGfxDevice:
    Version:  NULL 1.0 [1.0]
    Renderer: Null Device
    Vendor:   Unity Technologies
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in  0.093 seconds
Microsoft Media Foundation video decoding to texture disabled: graphics device is Null, only Direct3D 11 and Direct3D 12 (only on desktop) are supported.
UnloadTime: 0.676100 ms
```

uhh help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Server Build checked in build settings, uncheck it.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-game-wont-run.846679/